# I/O to device from kernel module fails with EFAULT

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

I have created block device in kernel module. When some I/O happens I read/write all data from/to another existing device (let's say `/dev/sdb`).

It opens OK, but read/write operations return 14 error(`EFAULT`,Bad Address). After some research I found that I need map address to user space(probably `buffer` or `filp` variables), but `copy_to_user` function does not help. Also I looked to `mmap()` and `remap_pfn_range()` functions, but I can not get how to use them in my code, especially where to get correct `vm_area_struct` structure. All examples that I found, used char devices and `file_operations` structure, not block device.

Any hints? Thanks for help.

Here is my code for reading:

```
mm_segment_t old_fs;
old_fs = get_fs();
set_fs(KERNEL_DS);
filp = filp_open("/dev/sdb",  O_RDONLY | O_DIRECT | O_SYNC, 00644);
if(IS_ERR(filp))
{
    set_fs(old_fs);
    int err = PTR_ERR(filp);
    printk(KERN_ALERT"Can not open file - %d", err);
    return;
}
else
{
    bytesRead = vfs_read(filp, buffer, nbytes, &offset);  //It gives 14 error
    filp_close(filp, NULL);
}
set_fs(old_fs);
```

Comment: `buffer` is a `char*` variable. We read data from `/dev/sdb` to it. It comes from `request` function like `request->buffer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better way for I/O to block device from kernel module. I have used `bio` structure for that. Hope this information save somebody from headache.

1) So, if you want to redirect I/O from your block device to existing block device, you have to use own `make_request` function. For that you should use `blk_alloc_queue` function to create queue for your block device like this:

```
device->queue = blk_alloc_queue(GFP_KERNEL);
blk_queue_make_request(device->queue, own_make_request);
```

Than into `own_make_request` function change `bi_bdev` member into `bio` structure to device in which you redirecting I/O and call `generic_make_request` function:

```
bio->bi_bdev = device_in_which_redirect;
generic_make_request(bio);
```

More information [here](http://lwn.net/Kernel/LDD3) at 16 chapter. If link is broken by some cause, here is name of the book - "Linux Device Drivers, Third Edition"

2) If you want read or write your own data to existing block device from kernel module you should use `submit_bio` function.

Code for writing into specific sector(you need to implement `writeComplete` function also):

```
void writePage(struct block_device *device,
           sector_t sector, int size, struct page *page)
{
    struct bio *bio = bio_alloc(GFP_NOIO, 1);
    bio->bi_bdev = vnode->blkDevice;
    bio->bi_sector = sector;
    bio_add_page(bio, page, size, 0);
    bio->bi_end_io = writeComplete;
    submit_bio(WRITE_FLUSH_FUA, bio);
}
```

Code for reading from specific sector(you need to implement `readComplete` function also):

```
int readPage(struct block_device *device, sector_t sector, int size,
     struct page *page)
{
    int ret;
    struct completion event;
    struct bio *bio = bio_alloc(GFP_NOIO, 1);
    bio->bi_bdev = device;
    bio->bi_sector = sector;
    bio_add_page(bio, page, size, 0);
    init_completion(&event);
    bio->bi_private = &event;
    bio->bi_end_io = readComplete;
    submit_bio(READ | REQ_SYNC, bio);
    wait_for_completion(&event);
    ret = test_bit(BIO_UPTODATE, &bio->bi_flags);
    bio_put(bio);
    return ret;
}
```

`page` can be allocated with alloc_page(GFP_KERNEL). Also for changing data in `page` use `page_address(page)`. It returns `void*` so you can interpret that pointer as whatever you want.